# inline suricata firewall bash script advice

Tags: bash, iptables

I have a firewall script that permits me to basically divert traffic to the suricata engine for inline processing. It looks like this. It's not mine, it's built by a 3rd party.

I'm trying to insert some statements in there that permit traffic from one subnet to another without being inspected by the suricata nfqueue engine.
Here's the script:

```
case "$MODE" in
        start)
                iptables -P FORWARD DROP
                (iptables -L FORWARD | grep NFQUEUE >/dev/null) || iptables -A FORWARD -j NFQUEUE

                iptables -P INPUT DROP
                (iptables -L INPUT -v | grep ACCEPT | grep lo >/dev/null) || iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
                (iptables -L INPUT -v | grep ACCEPT | grep eth0 >/dev/null) || iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
                (iptables -L INPUT | grep NFQUEUE >/dev/null) || iptables -A INPUT -j NFQUEUE
        ;;

        stop)
                iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
                (iptables -L FORWARD | grep NFQUEUE >/dev/null) && iptables -D FORWARD -j NFQUEUE

                iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
                (iptables -L INPUT -v | grep ACCEPT | grep lo >/dev/null) && iptables -D INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
                (iptables -L INPUT -v | grep ACCEPT | grep eth0 >/dev/null) && iptables -D INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
                (iptables -L INPUT | grep NFQUEUE >/dev/null) && iptables -D INPUT -j NFQUEUE
        ;;

        *)
                die unknown MODE: "$MODE"
        ;;
esac
```

I was hoping to insert logic that looked like this before you pushed the rest of the rules into suricata’s engine but I don't know how to do it or even if I wrote my iptables rules correctly..

Vlan1 to vlan2  and vlan2 to vlan1.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.250.104.0/25 -d 10.250.104.192/28 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.250.104.192/28 -d 10.250.104.0/25 -j ACCEPT
```

vlan 1 to vlan 20 and vlan20 to vlan1.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.250.104.0/25 -d 10.0.104.0/28 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.0.104.0/28 -d 10.250.104.0/25 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Is the question here about the iptables rules being correct? Or is the question about how to insert those rules into the script to do what you want? Both?

Comment: Actually, I solved this:

Comment: I solved this today but I'm not sure it's the most 'correct way... [link] http://pastebin.com/inzr348b

Comment: I'm running suricata inline over a 8021q trunked link between a cisco sibif'd rtr and a switch port trunk.. and was looking for a way to divert my LAN to LAN traffic around the scanning engine to improve inter vlan traffic bandwidth since I didn't want to scan that particular traffic anyway

Comment: Lots of trial and error went into this.